# Add to Grid more than one element

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, grid

Actually the problem is that I can not add my ListBoxItem in the Grid more than one element.

```
ListBoxItem _ListBoxItem = null;

   _ListBoxItem = LoginThread as ListBoxItem;
   LoginThread.Name = "LoginThread1";
   OkChild.Children.Insert(0, _ListBoxItem);

   _ListBoxItem = LoginThread as ListBoxItem;
   LoginThread.Name = "LoginThread2";
   OkChild.Children.Insert(1, _ListBoxItem);
```

Here's a get an error code: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.
If to add an empty ListBoxItem, then works fine, but it is to define and add your own ListBoxItem fails.
That is something like the following:

1) This method may add only one item in the Grid

```
ListBoxItem obj = new ListBoxItem ();
obj = MyListBoxItem;
```

2) And like this here is working

```
ListBoxItem obj = new ListBoxItem ();
for (int i = 0; i <100 500; i + +)
MyGrid.Children.Add (obj);
```

Actually what's the catch, please explain where I'm wrong, for earlier thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

A single instance of a visual element may only be added to the visual tree once. In your first code segment you are adding `LoginThread` to `OkChild` twice. Instead of creating a new `ListBoxItem`, you just assign `LoginThread` to `_ListBoxItem` everytime. A correct version of the code would be as follows:

```
ListBoxItem _ListBoxItem = null;

// Create a new ListBoxItem
_ListBoxItem = new ListBoxItem();
LoginThread.Name = "LoginThread1";
OkChild.Children.Insert(0, _ListBoxItem);

// Again, create a new ListBoxItem. We can reuse the same variable, _ListBoxItem, to refer
// to the new ListBoxItem, but it is very important that we actually create a new one.
_ListBoxItem = new ListBoxItem();
LoginThread.Name = "LoginThread2";
OkChild.Children.Insert(1, _ListBoxItem);
```

In your second code segment you write:

```
ListBoxItem obj = new ListBoxItem ();
obj = MyListBoxItem;
```

This first creates a new `ListBoxItem` and makes the variable `obj` refer to it. But the next line then redirects the variable `obj` to instead refer to whatever the variable `MyListBoxItem` is referring to. You have now completely lost any reference to the `ListBoxItem` you just created. Did you perhaps mean to write?:

```
ListBoxItem obj = new ListBoxItem ();
MyListBoxItem = obj;
```

In the third code segment you create one `ListBoxItem` and then add the same item to `MyGrid` over and over again in the `for`-loop. You probably meant to write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ListBoxItem obj = new ListBoxItem();
    MyGrid.Child.Add(obj);
}
```

See, now a new `ListBoxItem` is created in every iteration of the loop and then added to `MyGrid`.

I would recommend that you spend some more time learning about instances and variables in `C#`.